# Insert Query gets executed twice or more

Tags: php, mysql

```
$ad = '';
$campaign = '';
$medium = '';
$source = '';
$keyword = '';
$rd = '';
$product = '';
$cbr = '';
$cpc = '';

//    
// CODE HERE THAT REPLACES ALL VARIABLES FROM BEFORE EXCEPT $cpc;
//

$cpc_q = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT * FROM dashboard_cpc WHERE campaign=:campaign");
$cpc_q->execute(array(':campaign' => $campaign));
while ($cpc_ar = $cpc_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($cpc_ar['only_campaign'] == 1) {
        $cpc = $cpc_ar['cpc'];
    } else {
        $cpc_second_q = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT * FROM dashboard_cpc WHERE campaign=:campaign AND ad_content=:ad");
        $cpc_second_q->execute(array(':ad' => $ad, ':campaign' => $campaign));
        $cpc_ar = $cpc_second_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $cpc = $cpc_ar['cpc'];
    }
}



if ($cpc != '') {
    $query = $dbCon->prepare("
        INSERT INTO visits
            (ad, campaign, medium, source, keyword, uid, date, cpc) 
        VALUES
            (:ad, :campaign, :medium, :source, :keyword, :uid, :date, :cpc)
        ");

    $query->execute(array(':ad' => $ad, ':campaign' => $campaign, ':medium' => $medium, ':source' => $source, ':keyword' => $keyword, ':uid' => $uid, ':date' => $date, ':cpc' => $cpc));
}
```

the table called dashboard_cpc is looking like this:
[image]

No the problem I have: Whenever this code gets executed the insert is triggered a few times. Most of the times it is triggered two times. 
The only things that can change this are : $campaign and $ad. For different campaigns, the code gets triggered different number of times. Is my while causing this?

inb4 asking: If only_campaign is equal to 1, $ad should not matter anymore when choosing the cpc value. If it's 0, then it should also check for the $ad.

I hope I was clear enough.

PS: I also tried an SQL only solution which did not work quite well

```
 $query = $dbCon->prepare("
  INSERT INTO visits
  (ad, campaign, medium, source, keyword, uid, date, cpc)
  VALUES
  (:ad, :campaign, :medium, :source, :keyword, :uid, :date,
  (SELECT
  case oc.only_campaign
  when '1' then (SELECT oc.cpc)
  when '0' then (SELECT cpc FROM dashboard_cpc WHERE ad_content =:ad)
  end as cpc
  FROM
  (SELECT * FROM dashboard_cpc WHERE campaign =:campaign) AS oc)
  )
  ");
```

the problem here is that whenever I have more than one campaign with the same name (with only_campaign = 0 for all of them), the code above crashes as "oc" temporary table has multiple rows.

Thanks

Marius S